# Show that $\{A\in Hom(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^m ) | \mathrm{A \:has \:maximum \: Rank}\}$ is dense in $Hom(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^m )$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, group-homomorphism

Let $n, m \in \Bbb N$. Define $$D:= \{A\in Hom(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^m ) |A\mathrm{ \:has \:maximum \: Rank} \}$$
Now I have to show that $D$ is an open and dense subset of $Hom(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^m ) $

I don't really know how to approach this, does anyone have some ideas or tipps on how to show this? Thanks in advance!

$\{A\in Hom(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^m ) | \mathrm{A \:has \:maximum \: Rank}\}$ dense in $Hom(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^m )$

Comment: you have to prove that every linear operator is infinitely close to a max rank one

Comment: Hint: the determinant of a matrix is a (not identically zero) polynomial of the coefficients of the matrix, i.e. a continuous function.

Comment: @RiccardoCeccon ok, but my matrices aren't quadratic. How can I form the determinant? (also even If they were quadratic, could you maybe give me a bit more, since even with this tipp I'm still stuck)

Comment: @DeltaChief A non-square matrix has full rank if some quadratic sub-matrix of maximal size is invertible. This easily reduces to the quadratic case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make life easier, one should reduce to the case $m=n$ as follows: To make sure that a $m\times n$-matrix has full rank you only have to find a quadratic sub-matrix (of size $m$ or $n$, depending on which number is smaller) which is invertible. So you can just pick any quadratic sub-matrix of maximal size and if you can change this sub-matrix to have full rank, the whole matrix has full rank, regardless of all other entries. This reduces to the case $m=n$.

In the $n=m$-case you can make any matrix invertible by adding $\varepsilon I$ for small $\varepsilon$, because $\det(A+\varepsilon I)$ is a polynomial in $\varepsilon$, hence has only finitely many roots.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you explain the last part a bit more? So you want to find an $\varepsilon$ so that $\det(A+\varepsilon I) \not = 0$, if I understand correctly. How do you justify that there exists such an epsilon? (I don't understand the part about the roots)

Comment: Given any polynomial $f(x)$, how do you justify that there is some $x$ with $f(x) \neq 0$? This is trivial, isn't it?

Comment: Well If you put it like this... ;). Thanks for the explanation and the answer!